# didFailLoadWithError incorrectly reports no connection

Tags: uiwebview

I have an app with a standard view controller with multiple buttons on it. Each button links to a separate view controller with a unique UIWebView. Each UIWebView has didFailLoadWithError implemented and it seems to work fine: when I turn off wifi, and try to load the UIWebView from the main view controller page, I correctly get the error message from didFailLoadWithError. When I turn on wifi and load the UIWebView, it works fine - no error. However, when I click on a link within that UIWebView page, I get the didFailLoadWithError error again. Even more interesting, I clear the error message and the new page still loads from the link I just clicked, so I know the connection is good. Here is my implementation...does anyone know of a way to force didFailLoadWithError to only run once on first load and suppress it from running again once you verify a web connection is good?

```
@synthesize webView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Alert"    message:@"No Internet Connection - Please Check Your Network Settings and Try Again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:     @"http://www.site.com/index.html"]]];
    [webView addSubview:activity];
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0)
        target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
           }

- (void)loading {
    if (!webView.loading)
        [activity stopAnimating];
        else
            [activity startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: I tested this a bit more and found the issue is not in the code or in the didFailLoadWithError routine, but it is caused by a specific link. For some reason, all attempts to follow the following link from the UIWebView will result in a didFailLoadWithError, but all "normal" links do not cause the error. Here is the problematic link:  http://p.incmedia.incmediaservices.netdna-cdn.com/vod/incmedia.incmediaservices/003/800k/FTT_0014.mov

Comment: I'm having the same issue, ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem. Whats going on, is when you click on a link within the web view, while the page is still loading, you will get error `-999`. This translates to `NSURLErrorCancelled`.

You can find out more in the following link. Goto the `URL Loading System Error Codes` section. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html

In my code i was telling an alert view to pop up saying the internet connect was lost upon `-webView:didFailLoadWithError:` being called. I wrapped that code around a condition on the error object. Heres an example.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([error code] == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet || [error code] == NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Check internet connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```